# how to convert a normal mysql query in to codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to get the highest mark from mark table, but i have set the mark obtained as varchar becuase i want to store some text values in some cases.

when i write this in mysql it returns the highest mark as an integer value

```
SELECT MAX(`mark_obtained`) AS `mark_obtained` FROM `mark` WHERE `exam_id` = '1' AND `class_id` = '10' AND `section_id` = '32' AND `subject_id` = '21' AND `mark_obtained` BETWEEN 0 AND 100
```

this is the codeigniter method i wrote to obtained the highest mark,but when i give it prints the value it prints it always print the varchar value

```
   function get_highest_marks($exam_id, $class_id, $section_id, $subject_id) {

        $this->db->where('class_id', $class_id);
        $this->db->where('section_id', $section_id);
        $this->db->where('subject_id', $subject_id);
        $this->db->where( "mark_obtained BETWEEN 0 AND 100", NULL, FALSE );

        $highest_marks = $this->db->get('mark')->result_array();



        foreach ($highest_marks as $row) {


            echo $row['mark_obtained'];
        }
    }
```

so how to always print the highest integer value

Comment: use cast. for converting into integer.try edited answer.

Comment: did you try it with removing between condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_highest_marks($exam_id, $class_id, $section_id, $subject_id) {
        $this->db->select('MAX(mark_obtained) AS mark_obtained');
        $this->db->where('exam_id', $exam_id);
        $this->db->where('class_id', $class_id);
        $this->db->where('section_id', $section_id);
        $this->db->where('subject_id', $subject_id);
        $this->db->where('mark_obtained >=', 0);
        $this->db->where('mark_obtained <=', 100);
        $highest_marks = $this->db->get('mark')->result_array();
        foreach($highest_marks as $key=>$val) {
            echo $val = (int)$highest_marks[$key]['mark_obtained'];
        }
}
```

or

```
function get_highest_marks($exam_id, $class_id, $section_id, $subject_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(mark_obtained) AS mark_obtained FROM mark 
    WHERE exam_id = '".$exam_id."' AND class_id = '".$class_id."' AND section_id 
    = '".$section_id."' AND subject_id = '".$subject_id."' AND mark_obtained 
    BETWEEN 0 AND 100");
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
          $result = $query->row_array();
          echo $result['mark_obtained'];
    }
}
```

Comment: @shane: answer provided

Comment: it didnt work its not casting varchar values to int ..it prints the varchar values

Comment: place output which u got? or use type cast answer updated

Comment: out put is like this 89 97 9 0 99 99 becauase of casting issue its prints as a 0

Comment: @shane: try second query

Comment: i used the table $this->db->get('mark')->result_array(); but now it doesnt give an error or not showing data

Comment: but how to exclude any varchar value from select query

Comment: it worked finally MAX(CAST(mark_obtained AS UNSIGNED))

Comment: great finally got solution

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query.use `$this->db->select_max('column_name');`.Like this

```
    $this->db->select_max('CAST(mark_obtained AS UNSIGNED)');
    $this->db->where('class_id', $class_id);
    $this->db->where('section_id', $section_id);
    $this->db->where('subject_id', $subject_id);
    $this->db->where( "mark_obtained >=", 0);
    $this->db->where( "mark_obtained <=", 100);

    $highest_marks = $this->db->get('mark')->row();

    echo $highest_marks->mark_obtained;
```

Comment: i tried your method it prints varchar values as well,i want to exclude all the varchar values when it retrieves highest marks

Comment: varchar means.what result is printing this query.

Comment: just return `$highest_marks->mark_obtained;` from your method.

Comment: ok now it prints 0 instead of varchar value...but its still not picking the highest value

Comment: i think not need to between condition.Try removing between.

Comment: i tried that one it gives me an sql error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CAST(mark_obtained AS UNSIGNED) FROM `mark` WHERE `exam_id` = '1' AND `class_id`' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
$this->db->select_max('mark_obtained');
$this->db->where('exam_id', 1);
$this->db->where('class_id', 10);
$this->db->where('section_id', 32);
$this->db->where('subject_id', 21);
$this->db->where('mark_obtained >=','0');
$this->db->where('mark_obtained <=', '100');    
return $this->db->get('mark')->row()->mark_obtained;
```

Comment: is this possible to give like this     $this->db->where( 'FORMAT(mark_obtained,'int') >=', 0);
    $this->db->where( 'FORMAT(mark_obtained,'int') <=', 100);

Comment: datatype is varchar

Comment: please check the updated answer you need to put the value 0 and 100 in single quote

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
$data = array('exam_id'=>1,'class_id'=>10,'section_id'=>32,'subject_id'=>32);
$this->db->select_max('mark_obtained') as 'mark_obtained';
$this->db->from('mark');
$this->db->where($data);
$this->db->where('mark_obtained >=', 0);
$this->db->where('mark_obtained <=', 100);
return $this->db->get('mark')->row()->mark_obtained;
```